# Control script through modifying trigger files on unrelated website

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

For on-the-fly adjustment of a script distributed amongst multiple internal users, I have the idea to turn various features on/off by the presence or absence of trigger files on a public webserver.

For example, if `https://example.com/files/runTest1.txt` is present, then show the RunTest1 button. Or maybe, `runTest1.jpg`? One should be able to detect if the image is present? *(Confirmed, this works)*

However, I'm not sure (a) if accessing trigger data from a remote text file will work, or (b) how to configure it.

It would be great if I could put some switches (trigger words or key=value pairs) into a remote text file, read the file contents on page load, and set several options that way - but this morning I am drawing a blank on what that might look like.

Here is my current approach:

1. Create desired number of 55px x 1px transparent background png files
2. Inject each (invisible) trigger png file onto page via `<img>` tags
3. In a setTimeout, get the `.offsetWidth` for the injected png files
4. If source png file exists, width will be > 50px, else it will be < 50px (*allowing for padding/margins/etc*)
5. By determining if any given source png file exists or not, I can set switches that work across all scripts, tailored for individual users (*i.e. no need for separate scripts for each user*)

As I say, the above is working but what a kludge. Are there better ideas?